# Entity framework Lazyload issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using code first from databse and here are the classes:

```
[Table("Language")]
public partial class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        LocaleString = new HashSet<LocaleString>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LocaleString> LocaleStrings { get; set; }
}

[Table("LocaleStringResource")]
public partial class LocaleString
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

and when I say the localeString repository: repository.GetIQueryable()

the result is :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[LanguageId] AS [LanguageId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[LocaleStrings] AS [Extent1]}
```

and why I say  repository.GetIQueryable().ToList() the list of results include the Language property and the type is something like dynamicProxies.Language,It means the ToList also load the relation data or just because to see the result in debugger? Thanks

Comment: Shortly - the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is as you've pasted, EF is lazy-loading the language property in debugger. You can actually examine it: if you aren't on a fast connection there might be a slight delay/lag when you hover onto that property. Is that the case? If yes, then EF is lazy loading the property the moment you hover. You can be 100% sure by turning off lazy loading and trying the same. If it fails to load, then it was lazy loading.